# CFtpConnection::GetCurrentDirectory unresolved token error. Other functions like SetCurrentDirectory work though

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unmanaged, managed

The dll compiles fine as unmanaged code, however when I add /clr and change to Use MFC in a Shared DLL in the project properties, mfCFtpConnection::GetCurrentDirectory gives me LNK2028 and LNK2019 errors. Which are unresolved token and unresolved eternal symbol errors.

I have #include  and linked wininet.lib. So I am puzzled.

I read a post online where the user had this issue and it was related to mfc100.lib renaming CFtpConnection::GetCurrentDirectory to CFtpConnection::GetCurrentDirectoryA. There was no work around and a microsoft rep said it would be fixed in future versions of mfc100.lib. I do not know if that is the problem.

Here is the link to the post.
[Link to online Post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/558583/error-in-cftpconnection-getcurrentdirectory-inside-mfc100-dll)

Any ideas it is driving me crazy.

Also I tried CFtpConnection::GetCurrentDirectoryAsURL and the code compiled fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow? Could you post your code ? It will help us ... to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this error stems from the fact that there are some `#define`s used to sneak around CLR restrictions for MFC dlls.
If you're using VS2010, you can hover over the method name and you will see the `#define` statement that is renaming your method in the generated `.obj` file. Since it's been renamed, the other modules in your code won't be able to link to it.